# How do you reference a multi-class CSS Selector in Selenium when it is named similar to others?

Tags: html, selenium, css-selectors

I have a set of classes underneath the  of the HTML document which all share the same set of class names. These are all date pickers but the one that is currently on screen lacks a class name that the others have which is how I need to select it.

How do I write my CSS Selector so that it picks the  that has two class names but not the third?

I.E.:

```
<body>
    <div class="class-one class-two class-three"></div>
    <div class="class-one class-two class-three"></div>
    <div class="class-one class-two class-three"></div>
    <div class="class-one class-two class-three"></div>
    <div class="class-one class-two"></div>
</body>
```

I want a selector that picks the last div here. So I want it to say that it has "class-one" and "class-two" class names but does NOT have "class-three"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also will be worked the following CSS Selector:

```
div[class='class-one class-two']:not(.class-three)
```

PS: To disregard the spaces and the order of the classes use the following CSS Selector: `div.class-one.class-two:not(.class-three)`.

Comment: @Ratmir Asanov, `:not(.class-three)` is useless since you are selecting the exact class. So either `div[class='class-one class-two']` for an exact match on the class or 
 `div.class-one.class-two:not(.class-three)` to disregard the spaces and the order of the classes.

Comment: @FlorentB., I agree with you! I have updated my answer with remarks. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of selector

```
div.class-one.class-two
```

which will fetch all `div` nodes, you can use

```
div[class="class-one class-two"]
```

which will return you the last node only

There is also [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) syntax:

```
div:not(.class-three)
```

but I'm not sure whether it's applicable for Selenium

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to get the 'not' working but wasn't getting the syntax the right way round, this is great!